# How do I `cd` and then* `ls` automatically in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ls

I have found myself keep doing `cd some_dir` quickly followed by `ls` for quite some time now, and have been trying to write a bash alias to let me do this, such as:

```
alas cd="cd $@; ls";
```

Problem with this is you [can't have an input argument](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-pass-argument-to-alias-command/) in the middle of an alias (correct me if I'm wrong).

I've also tried defining my own shell function as suggested by [this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-pass-argument-to-alias-command/):

```
cd() { cd "$@"; ls; }
```

But the problem with this one is if I try to use it like so:

```
cd Documents
```

the shell exits with `[Process completed]`, rendering the shell useless... So how should I get around this?

Comment: I'd love a shell that had `alas` as a builtin.

Comment: I recommend you don't do this.  Make your alias named "`cdl`" or something else.  Otherwise, you'll get into this habit.  Worse: you could encounter times when you wouldn't want to ls.  e.g., when handling a remote filesystem, it may be slow.  When running `make`, a script might `cd` a lot, and there's no point in slowing the script down.  Simply, out of habit, you're best off trying to not conflict with widely deployed native commands you know about.

Comment: @RobDavis What is this "alas" program of which you spoke of?  (I realize it's been over three and a half years since you made that comment.)  Is this a third party program with a home page?

Comment: @TOOGAM Given that Rob Davis appears to no longer have an active account, you probably won't get an answer from him. But I suspect he was referring to the meaning of the word "[alas](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/alas)" as an expression of sorrow and not any specific program.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd() { builtin cd "$@" && ls; }
```

`builtin` makes the `cd` inside the function invoke the builtin `cd` command rather than trying to call the function recursively.

Comment: Is recursion actually a risk? I do `alias ls='ls --color'`, and it doesn't recurse. Nor does `'alias rm='rm -i'`

Comment: Those are aliases, not a functions. They don't work the same way. Try  `foo() { echo hello ; foo; }; foo;` (have your Ctrl-C ready).

Comment: Ah, quite right, wasn't paying enough attention.

Comment: Might be better to have `builtin cd "$@" && ls;` instead so that `ls` doesn't run if there is problem entering the directory (non-existent etc.), like what John Ledbetter mentioned in his answer.

Comment: Yep, that's much better; hadn't thought about that, thanks.

Comment: Just a question to @Mat: will the recursion in function start eating up my RAM?

Comment: @anishsane: a recursive function can eat up ram, yes. This answer isn't recursive though.

Comment: ^^ "This answer isn't recursive though": Yes, understood that :)

Answer (score 3):

I use a Bash function to automatically do an `ls` after I `cd`:

```
# Automatically do an ls after each cd
cd() {
  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    builtin cd "$@" && ls --group-directories-first
  else
    builtin cd ~ && ls --group-directories-first
  fi
}
```

Just add the above to your `~/.bashrc`

Personally I add it to my `~/.bash_functions` (which is sourced by my `~/.bashrc`)

Answer (score 2):

In GNU Bash,

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=ls
```

Comment: While this technically answers the question, as in it performs `ls` after a `cd`, it achieves this by naively running `ls` after _every_ command regardless of whether it's `cd` or not